# I am getting below error while starting of Tom Cat server

Tags: java

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
>   instance of class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.(CollectionFactory.java:64)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.(ContextLoader.java:153)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.createContextLoader(ContextLoaderListener.java:53)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:44)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4544)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5016)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1035)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:738)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1035)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:289)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:442)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:674)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:596)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431) Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   ... 24 more

I am using tom cat- 7, Maven version is 4.0.0
Can you please suggest me on this..
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are missing a dependency.  How can we help you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

`commons-logging` dependency is missing. it should be in lib directory or in pom dependency declaration.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: I added jar and dependency which are mentioned above. Now problem got solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need check commons-logging-1.2.jar in you tomcat lib.

some dependency  jar is in you project .but may not in tomcat.